# GeoHash Queries in Firebase with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geolocation

I'm super excited about the new geo query feature available in Firebase. I'm trying out the 'GeoFire/Utils' pod recently made available. I set up a test iOS app and here is the [repo](https://github.com/westsider/GeoHash/tree/main). I left the rules open if anyone wants to clone and try. My Firestore document looks like this.

```
date : January 29, 2021 at 1:29:00 PM UTC-8
geohash:"9mupwu3mkc"
id:"13101C7F-D7FF-4141-BC5A-76602173C096"
lat:33.6863622
lng:-117.8264411
ownerAddress:"1 Civic Center Plaza, Irvine CA 92606"
```

I am using the sample [code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries) from firebase. Here is the call to firebase

```
func getallDocs(radius: Double) {
    // Find pickups within 50km of Basecamp
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 33.9742268, longitude: -118.3947792)
    let radiusInKilometers: Double = radius

    // Each item in 'bounds' represents a startAt/endAt pair. We have to issue
    // a separate query for each pair. There can be up to 9 pairs of bounds
    // depending on overlap, but in most cases there are 4.
    let queryBounds = GFUtils.queryBounds(forLocation: center,
                                          withRadius: radiusInKilometers)
    let queries = queryBounds.compactMap { (any) -> Query? in
        guard let bound = any as? GFGeoQueryBounds else { return nil }
        return db.collection("pickups")
            .order(by: "geohash")
            .start(at: [bound.startValue])
            .end(at: [bound.endValue])
    }

    var matchingDocs = [QueryDocumentSnapshot]()
    // Collect all the query results together into a single list
    func getDocumentsCompletion(snapshot: QuerySnapshot?, error: Error?) -> () {
        guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else {
            print("Unable to fetch snapshot data. \(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }
        
        print("\nDocs: Count \(documents.count)")
        for document in documents {
            let lat = document.data()["lat"] as? Double ?? 0
            let lng = document.data()["lng"] as? Double ?? 0
            let ownerAddress = document.data()["ownerAddress"] as? String ?? "no address"
            let coordinates = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: lng)
            let centerPoint = CLLocation(latitude: center.latitude, longitude: center.longitude)

            // We have to filter out a few false positives due to GeoHash accuracy, but
            // most will match
            let distance = GFUtils.distance(from: centerPoint, to: coordinates)
            print("ownerAddress: \(ownerAddress), distance: \(distance) \tlat: \(lat), \(lng)")
            if distance <= radiusInKilometers {
                matchingDocs.append(document)
            }
        }
    }

    // After all callbacks have executed, matchingDocs contains the result. Note that this
    // sample does not demonstrate how to wait on all callbacks to complete.
    for query in queries {
        query.getDocuments(completion: getDocumentsCompletion)
    }
    print("Docs: \(matchingDocs.count)")
}
```

My distances are way off. Here is an example of my output, the top one is my query center. And with a query radius of 100,000 km I still don't get all of my addresses in California.

```
Home Base: 7401 Sepluveda, Los Angeles CA 90045, distance: 0.0  lat: 33.9742268, -118.3947792
ownerAddress: 1204 Mira Mar Ave, Long Beach CA 90301, distance: 31295.135631869747  lat: 33.781846, -118.1473443
ownerAddress: 625 Fair Oaks, Pasadena CA 91030, distance: 27608.75410615904     lat: 34.1181627, -118.1510438
```

My question is why is my distance so much greater than what google maps / reality is?

Comment: *firebaser here* I'm wondering if the value isn't actually in meters, despite what our docs say. Can you give it a try to see if the results make more sense when you interpret the radius as being in meters?

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen, Both you and firebase rock! I love your videos! Great thought. The distance from home base to the Long Beach pick up is 24.4 miles or 39.2 km (via highway miles). My geo query result is 31,295.. which if that's in meters would be 31.2 km - as the bird flies. So that's quite a bit more on target. The state of California has a length od 1,240 km, so If I want to include the entire state its 1.2 million meters.. I try to  pass that in as a double in swift but I was having trouble with the compiler saying that value is too large for a double

Comment: Yes, that was it I believe @FrankvanPuffelen. When I pass in 1,200,000 meters I get pickups in the entire state of California. I am not getting the bizarro swift error today. So the output for distance is in meters and I have to consider that the distance is not the highway miles I will get from google maps. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Phew, so that explains. Sorry you hit this issue, but I'm glad we seem to have found it. We had a mistake in this area in the Android and JavaScript libraries too, so I'll check what we need to change (docs and/or code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*firebaser here*

From our chat in the comments it seems that the `withRadius:` value is actually in meters, despite what the documentation says.

This is clearly not working as documented, so I filed a to update the docs. That change is coming in [here](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc/commit/1c4b155dacdf19fff1f11db877065f2b4f8159b3).